# The program executed by sudo obtains the wrong DBUS and env

Tags: linux, sudo

I need to use getenv to determine whether the system is X11 or Wayland, and DBUS to realize the screen capture function.
They work well without sudo.
However, when using sudo, getenv gets the wrong value and gdbus cannot locate DBUS.
I'm pretty sure this is a problem with sudo because I tried
`echo $WAYLAND_DISPLAY` and `sudo echo $Wayland_DISPLAY`, `d-feet` and `sudo d-feet`. They are right when they don't use sudo.
However, due to the requirements of other functions in the program, I have to use sudo. Is there any good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any good idea?

By default, `sudo` runs the command in a new, fresh environment. From `man sudo`:

```
 -E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
             existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error
             if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

 --preserve-env=list
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to add the comma-
             separated list of environment variables to those preserved from the user's
             environment.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not
             have permission to preserve the environment.  This option may be specified
             multiple times.
```

You can list the variables you want to preserve.

```
sudo --preserve-env=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS,DISPLAY,WAYLAND_DISPLAY,other_variables,etc command
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I want !